# XSLT - change of XPATH in a for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

My first message here, I hope I'll do it right! Any help or constructive help (I'm a beginner) is welcome!
I have a product which can have 2 differents names + some other properties. I wanted to have on row for each main and second nameS possible.

I called a template to display the main name and a another one to call properties of the product, no prob as the nodes are at the same "level".

Then I wanted to call a 2nd template to display, in the same row, each second name possible for each product and then call the properties template, problem is I can't come back to parent nodes once in the "for-each" function.

XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="SOF.xsl" ?>

<root>
    <intrants>
        <CCCs>
            <PPP>
                <nbID>01</nbID>
                <product-name>MainNameA</product-name>
                <int-composition>
                    <act-subs>
                        <act-sub>
                            <substance ref-type="substance" ref-id="00000000000000000001">subA</substance>
                            <variant>
                                <name>substanceA</name>
                            </variant>
                            <AS-concentration unite-id="10000000000000000001" unite="g/L">123.0</AS-concentration>
                        </act-sub>
                    </act-subs>
                </int-composition>
            </PPP>
            <PPP>
                <nbID>02</nbID>
                <product-name>MainNameB</product-name>
                <others-names> </others-names>
                <int-composition>
                    <act-subs>
                        <act-sub>
                            <substance ref-type="substance" ref-id="00000000000000000001">subA</substance>
                            <variant>
                                <name>substanceA</name>
                            </variant>
                            <AS-concentration unite-id="10000000000000000001" unite="g/L">123.0</AS-concentration>
                        </act-sub>
                    </act-subs>
                </int-composition>
            </PPP>
            <PPP>
                <nbID>03</nbID>
                <product-name>MainNameC</product-name>
                <others-names>
                    <other-name>
                        <type-name ref-type="type-name" ref-id="20150522093431975033" lib-court="SEC">Second name</type-name>
                        <name>SecondNameC</name>
                    </other-name>
                </others-names>
                <int-composition>
                    <act-subs>
                        <act-sub>
                            <substance ref-type="substance" ref-id="00000000000000000001">subA</substance>
                            <variant>
                                <name>substanceA</name>
                            </variant>
                            <AS-concentration unite-id="10000000000000000001" unite="g/L">123.0</AS-concentration>
                        </act-sub>
                    </act-subs>
                </int-composition>
            </PPP>
            <PPP>
                <nbID>04</nbID>
                <product-name>MainNameD</product-name>
                <others-names>
                    <other-name>
                        <type-name ref-type="type-name" ref-id="20150522093431975033" lib-court="SEC">Second name</type-name>
                        <name>SecondName1D</name>
                    </other-name>
                    <other-name>
                        <type-name ref-type="type-name" ref-id="20150522093431975033" lib-court="SEC">Second name</type-name>
                        <name>SecondName2D</name>
                    </other-name>
                </others-names>
                <int-composition>
                    <act-subs>
                        <act-sub>
                            <substance ref-type="substance" ref-id="00000000000000000001">subA</substance>
                            <variant>
                                <name>substanceA</name>
                            </variant>
                            <AS-concentration unite-id="10000000000000000001" unite="g/L">123.0</AS-concentration>
                        </act-sub>
                        <act-sub>
                            <substance ref-type="substance" ref-id="00000000000000000002">subB</substance>
                            <variant>
                                <name>substanceB</name>
                            </variant>
                            <AS-concentration unite-id="10000000000000000001" unite="g/kg">456.0</AS-concentration>
                        </act-sub>
                        <act-sub>
                            <substance ref-type="substance" ref-id="00000000000000000003">subC</substance>
                            <variant>
                                <name>substanceC</name>
                            </variant>
                            <AS-concentration unite-id="10000000000000000001" unite="%/L">678.0</AS-concentration>
                        </act-sub>
                    </act-subs>
                </int-composition>
            </PPP>
        </CCCs>
    </intrants>
</root>
```

XLM :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Rep</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table style="width:100%">

                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Composition</th>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="root/intrants/CCCs/PPP">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:call-template name="displayMN">
                            <xsl:with-param name="MN" select="." />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                    <xsl:for-each select="/root/intrants/CCCs/PPP">
                        <xsl:if test="count(others-names/other-name) &gt; 0">
                            <xsl:for-each select="others-names/other-name/name">
                                <tr>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="displaySN">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="SN" select="/root/intrants/CCCs/PPP"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Main Product -->

    <xsl:template name="displayMN">
        <xsl:param name="MN"/>
        <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="displayMainName">
                <xsl:with-param name="name" select="product-name"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>

        <xsl:call-template name="displayCore">
            <xsl:with-param name="Produit" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Second Product -->

    <xsl:template name="displaySN">
        <xsl:param name="SN"/>
        <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="displaySecondName">
                <xsl:with-param name="name" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>

        <xsl:call-template name="displayCore">
            <xsl:with-param name="Produit" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Core -->
    <xsl:template name="displayCore">
        <xsl:param name="Produit"/>

        <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="displaynbID">
                <xsl:with-param name="nbID" select="nbID"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>

        <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="displayCompositionEN">
                <xsl:with-param name="Composition" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>

    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Main Name -->

    <xsl:template name="displayMainName">
        <xsl:param name="name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Second Name -->

    <xsl:template name="displaySecondName">
        <xsl:param name="name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- IDnb -->

    <xsl:template name="displaynbID">
        <xsl:param name="nbID"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nbID"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Composition EN -->

    <xsl:template name="displayCompositionEN">
        <xsl:param name="Composition"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="int-composition/act-subs/act-sub">
            <xsl:call-template name="displaySubstanceEN">
                <xsl:with-param name="AS" select="substance"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="SACc" select="AS-concentration"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text> + </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Substance EN-->

    <xsl:template name="displaySubstanceEN">
        <xsl:param name="AS"/>
        <xsl:param name="SACc"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$AS"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="$SACc"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="$SACc/@unite"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see in the resulting transformation, I can't reach back properties informations:

[image: Result]

Comment: What should be in *ID* and *Composition* columns in rows with *Second names*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that e.g. in row containing *SecondNameC*, in the remaining columns
there should be displayed the same values as for *MainNameC*, i.e. `03` and
`subA 123.0 g/L`.

The script below does the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    doctype-system= "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head><title>Rep</title></head>
      <body>
        <table style="width:80%" border="1">
          <tr><th>Name</th><th>ID</th><th>Composition</th></tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="root/intrants/CCCs/PPP">
            <tr>
              <xsl:call-template name="displayMN">
                <xsl:with-param name="MN" select="." />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:for-each select="root/intrants/CCCs/PPP">
            <xsl:variable name="MN" select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="count(others-names/other-name) &gt; 0">
              <xsl:for-each select="others-names/other-name/name">
                <tr>
                  <xsl:call-template name="displaySN">
                    <xsl:with-param name="MN" select="$MN"/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Main Product -->
  <xsl:template name="displayMN">
    <xsl:param name="MN"/>
    <td>
      <xsl:call-template name="displayMainName">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="product-name"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </td>
    <xsl:call-template name="displayCore">
      <xsl:with-param name="Produit" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Second Product -->
  <xsl:template name="displaySN">
    <xsl:param name="MN"/>
    <td>
      <xsl:call-template name="displaySecondName">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </td>
    <xsl:call-template name="displayCore">
      <xsl:with-param name="Produit" select="$MN"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Core -->
  <xsl:template name="displayCore">
    <xsl:param name="Produit"/>
    <td>
      <xsl:call-template name="displaynbID">
        <xsl:with-param name="nbID" select="$Produit/nbID"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:call-template name="displayCompositionEN">
        <xsl:with-param name="Composition" select="$Produit"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Main Name -->
  <xsl:template name="displayMainName">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Second Name -->
  <xsl:template name="displaySecondName">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- IDnb -->
  <xsl:template name="displaynbID">
    <xsl:param name="nbID"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$nbID"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Composition EN -->
  <xsl:template name="displayCompositionEN">
    <xsl:param name="Composition"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Composition/int-composition/act-subs/act-sub">
      <xsl:call-template name="displaySubstanceEN">
        <xsl:with-param name="AS" select="substance"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="SACc" select="AS-concentration"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text> + </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Substance EN-->
  <xsl:template name="displaySubstanceEN">
    <xsl:param name="AS"/>
    <xsl:param name="SACc"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$AS"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="$SACc"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="$SACc/@unite"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/asnmyT

I see that you forgot that the context item is changed, e.g. in `for-each` loop.

Note also that I changed *displaySN* template. It contains `MN` parameter,
referring to the "main" (PPP) element.

There are also some changes in *displayCompositionEN* template.

I added also `xsl:output` element with `doctype-public` and `doctype-system`
attributes to generate XHTML output, as to obtain HTML view in
*xsltransform* test site. But if you don't need it, just delete it.

Comment: Indeed I wanted to display the sames values for the Main name and the Second name of a product. Your script worked perfectly, many thanks! (I didn't know the website you linked, it's very convenient)

I have a question though, I don't understand the "$Produit/nbID" or "$Composition/int-composition/..." , I knew $ just to get the value-of a node.

About the "for-each" loop, I noticed it changed the path of templates called inside it but didn't know how to change it, if I understand correctly you used a static variable to "force" the path to stay the same while in the loop?

Comment: Probably you have met with construction like *$xxx* as a reference to a variable. And now a bit of complication: If *xxx* contains an **XML element** with its **children elements** then *$xxx/yyy* is a reference to *yyy* element contained in *$xxx*. And as far as changes of context element are concerned: Each e.g. *for-each* loop changes the context element to the current element of the loop. To refer to the current element from the "outer context" we often use a variable holding the needed element and refer to it in such a loop. Search the Web, there is plenty of descriptions on this issue.